# Bayes rules for 2 causes

Tags: statistics, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Let's say I have $y \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow x \leftarrow z \in \mathbb{R}^k $. I think I model $p(x,y,z) = p(x|y,z)p(z)p(y)$?

From that, I think that bayes rule says that

$$
p(z,y|x) = \frac{p(x|y,z)p(z)p(y)}{p(x)}
$$

Can I also derive that
$$
p(z,y|x) = \frac{p(x|y,z)p(z)p(y|x)p(x)}{p(x)} = p(x|y,z)p(z)p(y|x) \text{?}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your derivation, you are implicitly implying that:
$$p(y)=p(y|x)p(x)$$
which is true unless $p(x,y)=p(y)$, because $p(x,y)=p(y|x)p(x)$

So do you also want to assume $p(x,y)=p(y)$? It is up to you, as you already have some assumption about joint distribution of $x,y,z$